# find the index of the first value in x that is greater than 0.999

Tags: python, indexing

I am confused with this question, how can I solve this?, I try something like this below without index how can I combine them together? Thank you

Q.Try to find the index of the first value in x that is greater than 0.999 using a for loop and break.

Hint: try iterating over range(len(x)).

````
for x in range(len(x)):
    if x > 0.999:
        break

print("The answer is", x)```
````

Comment: hey, so what s the output that you get? and what s the input? and what output did you expect? this would help people with your question, if they can see more details on what's going on, what you've tried, etc..

Comment: Before you post here, we expect you to trace your code to *try* understand what it's doing, even if you don't know how.  You start with some sequence `x` and then overwrite its value with a loop variable.  Your loop at least *tires* to count upward from 0.  Just how do you think this is going to solve the problem you state?

Comment: You need to trace your code.  You need to return to your tutorial materials to learn the difference between a list and a subscript.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way to achieve this is using [**`next()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#next) and [**`enumerate()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with **generator expression** as:

```
>>> x = [1, 3, 1.5, 7, 13, 9.2, 19]
>>> num = 2.7

>>> next(i for i, e in enumerate(x) if e > num)
1
```

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns the index along with element while iterating over the list. Because `3` is first value in `x` which is greater that `2.7`, above code returned the index of `3` which is `1`.

If it is must for you to use `range(len(x))`, then you can update above logic (it is entirely unnecessary though) as:

```
>>> next(i for i in range(len(x)) if x[i] > num)
1
```

---

**Issue with your code** is that while iterating the list, you are checking the value returned by `range()` to make a comparison `0.999`. Instead, you need to use it as an index and compare against the corresponding value of `x` list. Also, you are using your temporary variable as `x` while iterating in `for` loop, which is same as variable holding your list. You can fix your code as:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] > 0.999:
        break
```

Comment: @Aurz In case you reviewed it earlier, please recheck it now. I didn't understood the problem earlier that you are looking for index. I have updated the answer to return the index now

Answer (score 0):

If you really want you use a for loop with a break, you can use enumerate.

```
x = [0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 0.4, 0.5, 6]

for i, num in enumerate(x):
    if num > 0.999:
        break
print("The answer is", i)
#The answer is 4
```